# Missing method Class Text_feild .getContents

Tags: watir

I am trying to use the .getContents method for Watir, but it says that the method does not exist. So i tried to update Watir, but i already have the latest version. 
This is the line of code i was trying to use

> Provence = e.frame(:name => "content").frame(:name =>
>   "main").text_field(:name => "txtLocDesc").getContents

And then get and method missing error.

Answer (score 1):

Use #value method instead for getting value attribute for input field:

```
e.frame(:name => "content").frame(:name => "main").text_field(:name => "txtLocDesc").value
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think `getContents` will return text field value? I do not see that method in [watir-classic](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-classic) or [watir-webdriver](http://watir.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/) gem API.

Comment: I saw a .getContents method on a webpage for watir webdriver.

Comment: Where? Please post link to the page.

Comment: Sorry I looked for the site, but I unable to find it. If I ever see the site again I will bring it to your attention.